# Recursive calculation - How would it be started?

Tags: probability, recursion

First off, let me assure you that this is my very ***last*** resource. I have tried everything, because I understand that posting a question that needs a hyperlink to be understood is annoying. But I would truly, truly appreciate some help in just getting the calculation started.

The post is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/212305/67822), and it deals with the expected number of dice rolls before all sides are seen three times. A recursive formula is generated:

$$e(\mathbf{i}) = \frac{d + i_1 e(\mathbf{i}\cdot 1) + \cdots + i_n e(\mathbf{i}\cdot n)}{d - i_0}$$

which I interpret as follows:

1. The vector $\mathbf{i}$ is $\small [\text{no. of sides we need to see 0 times;}\,\,\,\text{no. sides need to see 1 time;}\,\,\,\text{no. sides need to see 2 times;}\,\,\,\text{no. sides need to see 3 times}]=[i_0,i_1,i_2,i_3]=[0;\,0;\,0;\,6]$.

   The entries in the vector $\mathbf{i}$, $i_j$ indicating the $\text{no. of }\color{blue}{\text{die faces}} \text{ that need to be seen } j \text{ times}.$
   And $j$ ranging from $1$ to $n=3$ indexing the $\text{no. of } \color{red}{\text{times}} \text{ we need to see } i_j \text{ faces}.$
2. So $e(\mathbf{i})$ is the expectation of such an event: all sides being seen three times.
3. $\mathbf{i}\cdot j$ is defined as the operation that brings the $\mathbf i$ from $[0,0,0,6]$ to $[0,0,1,5]$ when any face appears; and from $[0,0,1,5]$ to $[0,1,0,5]$ if the same die happens to appear on the second roll, etc.
4. Every transition between $\mathbf i$ vectors will occur with probability $i_j/\text{no. sides}.$

Again, my most profuse apologies for the painful introduction.

Here is the question:

How would one start this frightening computation if condemned to do it **manually**? To begin with, we see that in the formula there are expectations on the RHS and LHS of the equation. I guess we could write down all possible transitions in a maddening tree.

It is also unclear to me why there is a $1$ built-in the equation. But in any event, I know that there is a way to tackle this calculation and get to the figure of $32.677$:

$$e(0,0,0,6) = \frac{2\,286\,878\,604\,508\,883}{69\,984\,000\,000\,000}\approx 32.677.$$

---

[NOTE TO SELF](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Dice)

Comment: @mvw I just re-ran the R code, and it doesn't really produce the figures in the fraction in the post. I don't know how he calculates that astronomical numerator (or the denominator).

Comment: Hm, you are right: the code is the simulation he wrote to check his earlier result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$
e(\mathbf{i}) = \frac{d + i_1 e(\mathbf{i}\cdot 1) + \cdots + i_n e(\mathbf{i}\cdot n)}{d - i_0}
$$
features a function $e$ which takes a $n+1$ vector $i = (i_0, \dotsc, i_n)$.
That funny notation $i \cdot n = f(i, j)$ takes a $n+1$ vector $i$ and some index $j$ and computes another $n+1$ vector.

So computing $e$ for $i = (0,0,0,6)$ will need a bunch of evaluations of $e$ for different $i$ vectors, those that result from those dot operations $f$.

The recursion seems to stop when at some point $e(d,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ is reached, which seems to be $0$.

So
$$
e(\mathbf{i}) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } i = (d,\dotsc) \\
\frac{d + i_1 e(\mathbf{i}\cdot 1) + \cdots + i_n e(\mathbf{i}\cdot n)}{d - i_0} & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
has to implemented and called for $i = (0,0,0,6)$. A language with arbitrary long integer arithmetic support should be used.

**Update:**

I told that whole story to my friend Ruby, see [here](https://gist.github.com/372da2ae85000d731ca8141047df60bb). 
She gave [this answer](https://gist.github.com/f2f823473ef4a0a6018cef69d5096ae3).

The important line, which prevents infinite recursion, has the comment "important" attached to it.

Comment: First off, thank you. You are offering your help, and I needed it, because all along I felt like I somehow had to see as self-evident the plugging of the numbers into the closed formula. So it's more involved as per your last line. In all honesty, I had understood the rest, and so I wonder if you could extend a bit your answer in terms of what possibly went on to end up with a fraction.

Comment: I nailed it. Oeff.

Comment: Fabulous! That is all needed to know: you can't just solve this in "closed form" with pen and paper.

Comment: @AntoniParellada The Ruby code uses arrays for the $i$ vectors (supported in R and Pyhon). The $e$  results are fractions of large integers. If there is some support for large integers it should be easy.

Comment: @AntoniParellada My problem here was figuring out the recurrence at all, reproducing the calculated value. It might be possible to bring this into closed form. It seems mostly linear but has a multidimensional index.

Comment: I am posting here for reference a [translation of your code into R](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Dice) (it is not my work).